# How do I create a repeatable random shuffle of date time data to calculate the mean diff time

Tags: r, datetime, mean, difftime

I have a dataset of 1,000s of date times of events, event A and event B. I am looking to test if there is some dependence between them. To do so I wish to randomly shuffle the times in A and B, calculate the diff time between each observation i.e. A to B, then calculate the mean of all diff times. I wish to repeat this test 100s of times.

Im therefore looking for a loop or function rather than copy paste the code.

```
# the data frame is structured like this with many more observations

set.seed(10)

A <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12)

B <- sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by="day"), 12)

df <- data.frame(A, B)
```

I have been able to generate the output needed as follows, but need to repeat this many time, i.e. have 100s of mean_shuffled results

```
shuffled_A = sample(df$A)
shuffled_B = sample(df$B)

df_shuffled <- data.frame(shuffled_A, shuffled_B)

df_shuffled$diff <- difftime(df_shuffled$shuffled_B, df_shuffled$shuffled_A)

mean_shuffled <- mean(df_shuffled$diff)
```

following @jblood94 comments the below has been added

```
# the data frame is structured like this with many more observations

set.seed(100)

A <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 120)

B <- A + 2 # as I am testing that B is dependent on A, so B always takes place after A

df <- data.frame(A, B)

df = transform(df, C = sample(A), D = sample(B), E = sample(A), G = sample(B) ) # to create two shuffled diff times

df$diff <- difftime(df$B, df$A) # observed data
df$diff_shuffle1 <- abs(difftime(df$D, df$C, units = "days")) # A and B are at random times but I have added abs() as the diff time can be positive or negative
df$diff_shuffle2 <- abs(difftime(df$G, df$E, units = "days")) # A and B are at random times 2

mean(df$diff) # observed mean
mean(df$diff_shuffle1) # shuffled time difference between A and B is they happen at random times
mean(df$diff_shuffle2) # shuffled time difference between A and B is they happen at random times
```

Comment: Sampling without replacement, `mean_shuffled` will always be `(sum(B) - sum(A))/nrow(df)`=`2453.833 days`.

Comment: thanks @jblood94 well spotted. I have edited the code to create an example which is more accurate to my actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap what you've done in a `for()` loop for a given number of loops/simulations
`nsims` and track each simulation `sim` as it loops around and add the result each to the `output`. Note the static `data` name, and the dynamic `df` in the loop.

```
set.seed(100)

A <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 120)
B <- A + 2 # as I am testing that B is dependent on A, so B always takes place after A
data <- data.frame(A, B)

nsims <- 100
sim <- 1
output <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:nsims){
df = transform(data, C = sample(A), D = sample(B), E = sample(A), G = sample(B) ) # to create two shuffled diff times
df$diff <- difftime(df$B, df$A) # observed data
df$diff_shuffle1 <- abs(difftime(df$D, df$C, units = "days")) # A and B are at random times but I have added abs() as the diff time can be positive or negative
df$diff_shuffle2 <- abs(difftime(df$G, df$E, units = "days")) # A and B are at random times 2
obsM <- mean(df$diff) # observed mean
shuf1M <- mean(df$diff_shuffle1) # shuffled time difference between A and B is they happen at random times
shuf2M <- mean(df$diff_shuffle2) # shuffled time difference between A and B is they happen at random times
out <- data.frame(obsM,shuf1M,shuf2M,sim)
output <- rbind(output,out)
sim <- sim+1
}

output
```